# FastAPI's Depends() causes "Incompatible default for argument" error in mypy

Tags: python, types, fastapi, mypy

I have this example code.

```py
def get_test(q: str) -> str:
    return 'str str str' + q


@router_user.put(
    "/", response_model=schemas.UpdateUserRequest, tags=["User and Authentication"]
)
async def update_user(
        data: schemas.UpdateUserRequest,
        q: str = Depends(logic.get_test),
        db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
        user: models.User = Depends(logic.get_curr_user_by_token),
):
    print(q)
```

when checking it with mypy, I always get an error

```bash
app/api/user/router.py:74: error: Incompatible default for argument "q" (default has type "Depends", argument has type "str")  [assignment]
```

Comment: I fixed get_curr_user_by_token to get_test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've used an incorrect import.

I've cleaned up your code sample and added imports, and the following does pass `mypy`:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends


def get_test(q: str) -> str:
    return "str str str" + q


router_user = APIRouter()


@router_user.put("/")
async def update_user(
    q: str = Depends(get_test)
) -> None:
    print(q)
```

However, if I replace the imports with

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.params import Depends
```

Then I get the same error you got from mypy.

I'm guessing your IDE incorrectly completed the import from `fastapi.params` instead of directly from `fastapi`. If you check the official [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#import-depends), you'll see that `Depends` should be imported directly from `fastapi`.

### Why this happens

`params.Depends` is a class defined [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/60ef67a66b1e0cadc2f4b4d6ea9f84baec8768f3/fastapi/params.py#L359). However, if you use that directly, it will be a type error whenever you write something like `x: str = Depends(...)`, because the `params.Depends` class is not compatible with `str`. What we really want is for mypy to ignore the type of `Depends()` and assume it's compatible with any type.

That's why the `Depends` in `fastapi` is actually a wrapper function around `params.Depends` [defined](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/60ef67a66b1e0cadc2f4b4d6ea9f84baec8768f3/fastapi/param_functions.py#L278) as returning `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like your `get_curr_user_by_token` returns `models.User`. `Depends` itself doesn't change the type of result, so you just use the one that is returned by thing inside `Depends`.

```
q: models.User = Depends(logic.get_curr_user_by_token),
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the function name, there should be a get_test function, not get_curr_user_by_token.

Comment: get_curr_user_by_token also returns a string, but I simplified it to ask a question. Both options give the same error with mypy.